# Antlr hidden channel whitespace problem

Tags: whitespace, antlr, channel

I have the following Antlr grammar:

```
grammar MyGrammar;

doc :   intro planet;
intro   :   'hi';
planet  :   'world';
MLCOMMENT 
    :   '/*' ( options {greedy=false;} : . )* '*/' { $channel = HIDDEN; };
WHITESPACE : ( 
    (' ' | '\t' | '\f')+
  |
    // handle newlines
    ( '\r\n'  // DOS/Windows
      | '\r'    // Macintosh
      | '\n'    // Unix
    )
    )
 { $channel = HIDDEN; };
```

In the ANTLRWorks 1.2.3 interpreter, the inputs `hi world`,`hi/**/world` and `hi /*A*/ world` work, as expected.

However, the input `hiworld`, which *shouldn't* work, is also accepted.
How do I make `hiworld` fail? How do I force at least one whitespace(or comment) between "hi" and "world"?

Note that I've used only MLCOMMENT and WHITESPACE in this example to simplify, but other kinds of comments would be supported.

Comment: Well, I don't know Antlr, but wouldn't "doc: intro WHITESPACE planet" or something like this be most obvious?

Comment: Because the channel WHITESPACE is hidden, that causes a MismatchedTokenException.

Comment: So can't you create another whitespace grammar that is not hidden and use it?

Comment: I can, and I am temporarily using your method, but why would every single tutorial suggest either using the HIDDEN channel or skip() then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a general ID token. Since the lexer builds the longest token it can, it would see the input "hiworld" as a single word since it's longer than "hi" or "world" by themselves. Such a rule might look like:

```
ID : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+;
```

As an example, that's exactly how parsers for programming languages separate the "do" keyword from "double" (keyword type, starts with 'do') or "done" (variable name).

Comment: This answer just made so many things click in my head. thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way to make the string `hiworld` fail is to use a validating semantic predicate that is guaranteed to fail, as follows:

```
doc:      intro planet;
failure : 'hiworld' { false }?;
intro   : 'hi';
planet  : 'world';
// rest of grammar omitted
```

Comment: Very interesting, but if I added every single possible failure case to more complex grammars, the number of failure situations would grow exponentially.